# Calling move camera from another function (Ionic native google maps)

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to run map.moveCamera(position) outside the load map function. It's inside the same page as the map but in another function GetCurrentLocation().

However, I get an error when calling the function:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_this.map.moveCamera')

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  LatLng,
  CameraPosition
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform, private googleMaps: GoogleMaps, private geolocation: Geolocation, public events: Events, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController)  {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      console.log("constructor ran");
      this.loadMap();
    });
    events.subscribe('change:location', () => {
      this.GetCurrentLocation();
    });
  }

  GetCurrentLocation(){

    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true }).then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp.coords.latitude+", "+resp.coords.longitude);
      let location = new LatLng(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);
console.log("location= " +location);

      let position: CameraPosition = {
        target: location,
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 20
      };
      console.log("position= " +position);

      this.map.moveCamera(position); **//<- ERRORING HERE**

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
  }

  loadMap() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true }).then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp.coords.latitude+", "+resp.coords.longitude);
      let location = new LatLng(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);

    // create a new map by passing HTMLElement
    let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');

    let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element);

    // listen to MAP_READY event
    // You must wait for this event to fire before adding something to the map or modifying it in anyway
    map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(
      () => {
        console.log('Map is ready!');
        // Now you can add elements to the map like the marker
      }
    );

    // create CameraPosition
    let position: CameraPosition = {
      target: location,
      zoom: 18,
      tilt: 20
    };

    // move the map's camera to position
    map.moveCamera(position);


    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });


  } // End of load map
}
```

**And print out from the IOS sim console**

```
Jun 22 14:40:21 App[53930]: 37.785834, -122.406417
Jun 22 14:40:21 App[53930]: location= 37.785834,-122.406417
Jun 22 14:40:21 App[53930]: position= [object Object]
Jun 22 14:40:21 App[53930]: Error getting location TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.map.moveCamera')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing a map that was never assigned.

Instead of doing

```
  let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element);
```

make that

```
this.map = this.googleMaps.create(element);
```

then everywhere you use map, make sure you use this.map.